# Add a subcollection without knowing the document ID

Tags: firebase

In the firebase, I have a collection("users"), which have several documents. The document IDs are auto generated, and I want to add a subcollection into one of the document. I have query the doc ID but do not know what should I do next do correctly add the subcollection.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTpyQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code as a text, not image.
For what you are trying to do, you need to use:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(InsertYourDocId).collection(nameOf sucollectionYouwantToCreateOrRead).add({'title':title.value})
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to insert the doc.id before, but always got firebase.firestore... is not a funtion error. I assigned like var id = doc.id , and insert the id into firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(id).collection("name").... then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('users').where("name", "==", "ros corn" ).get().then(snapshot=>{
    const collectionId = snapshot?.docs[0]?.id
    firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(collectionId). add({
// Add what you want here
}).finally(() =>console.log(`Added`) ) 
} )
```